# Linq Except not functioning as expected - duplicate items

Tags: c#, entity-framework

**New Question**

After going round the houses a little, I don't think `Except` is the issue. I think selecting from the database is at fault. Therefore I have raised a new question [Where returns wrong record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539709/linq-where-returns-wrong-record). This question will be closed - or I'll ammend with the answer from the other question.

I'm trying to use the Linq `Except()` method with a custom comparer. I thought everything was working as my dataset was shrunk massively from 2k records to just 62. However within the 62 remaining records I've got a duplicate (item that already exists in the database) and I'm not sure how.

Here's my duplicate entry in the watch window:

[image]

And similarly the entry in the database (PostcodeKey and Zone_ID are a compound primary key)

[image]

I'm simply supposed to be removing from my collection any items that already exist in the database (this is via a CSV import) before saving:

```
IEnumerable<ZoneMapping> items // parameter passed in

// Exclude any items that we already have
items = items.Except(this.context.ZoneMappings.Include("Zone"), new ZoneMappingComparer()).ToList();

// Process all the items and save them
foreach (ZoneMapping item in items)
{
    this.context.ZoneMappings.Add(item);
}

this.context.SaveChanges();
```

I've verified that the database count and the `ZoneMappings.Count()` on my context are the same which they are. My comparer is quite simple:

```
public class ZoneMappingComparer : IEqualityComparer<ZoneMapping>
{
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public bool Equals(ZoneMapping x, ZoneMapping y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null || y == null)
            return false;

        if (x.PostcodeKey == "2214" && y.PostcodeKey == "2214")
            Debugger.Break();

        // Compare the Postcode Key
        int compareResult = x.PostcodeKey.CompareTo(y.PostcodeKey);
        if (compareResult != 0)
            return false;

        // Compare the Zone
        if (x.Zone == null && y.Zone == null)
            return true;

        // Compare the Zone
        if (x.Zone == null || y.Zone == null)
            return false;

        compareResult = x.Zone.ID.CompareTo(y.Zone.ID);
        return compareResult == 0;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public int GetHashCode(ZoneMapping obj)
    {
        return obj.PostcodeKey.GetHashCode() + ((obj.Zone != null) ? obj.Zone.ID.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've put a Debugger.Break() in there, this fires and by the end of the method `compareResult` is 0.

If I continue execution till the save however I get an UpdateException with the following message:

> {"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.NetC_EF_ZoneMapping'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.NetC_EF_ZoneMapping'. The duplicate key value is (2214, 257).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Have I misunderstood how Except should be working? Or am I missing something else obvious?

**EDIT**

I've tried Chris suggestion, may be a red herring but I've switched to populating my list manually:

```
// Exclude any items that we already have
items = new List<ZoneMapping>() { new ZoneMapping() { PostcodeKey = "2214", Zone = new Zone() { ID = 257 } } };
items = items.Except(this.context.ZoneMappings.Include("Zone"), new ZoneMappingComparer()).ToList();

ZoneMapping mapping = this.context.ZoneMappings.Include("Zone").Where(z => z.PostcodeKey == "2214" && z.Zone.ID == 257).First();
var comparer = new ZoneMappingComparer();
if (comparer.Equals(items.ToList()[0], mapping))
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

Oddly at this point my Zone from the context is the wrong one:

[image]

Another picture to illustrate the wrong record being returned and the SQL produced (which looks fine). If I run an automated test to the same affect it works correctly and returns the correct record.

[image]

Here's my ZoneMapping class:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Represents a mapping between a postcode and a zone
/// </summary>
[Table("NetC_EF_ZoneMapping")]
public class ZoneMapping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the postcode identifier
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public String PostcodeKey { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Zone identifier
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public Zone Zone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You look like you've got the right idea. If something is in `this.context.ZoneMappings.Include("Zone")` then it shouldn't be in `items`. Have you tried just setting the initial items to just the breaking one and `Excepting` with its theoretical match from the database and stepping through making sure your comparer works as expected (or simplifying to some unit tests that pass in the appropriate objects). I assume the duplicate key is a mix of the postcodekey and the zone id?

Comment: Not really related to your problem, but why do you use `CompareTo` instead of `Equals`? You clearly only care about equality and not about order. Also, you should use `Object.Equals(a, b)` instead of `a.Equals(b)` to prevent null reference exceptions (e.g. when `x.PostcodeKey` is null).

Comment: @cremor: Pass! I'll switch over as that makes more sense.

Comment: @cremor If an item appears twice in the initial list and once in the second list, both entries should be removed in the result, right?

Comment: @Chris: I've tried making a change like you suggested, interestingly my attempt to simulate it is grabbing the wrong ID however.

Comment: @BenAaronson Sorry, my comment was wrong, I've deleted it.

Comment: What do you mean by grabbing the wrong ID?

Comment: @BenAaronson: If you look at my watch window the mapping.Zone.ID is 256 - I asked for 257 in my Linq Where clause though.

Comment: Out of interest, on the line where you get `mapping`, try adding a `.ToList()` before the `Where`, and see if you still get the one with the wrong ID.

Comment: @BenAaronson: I've tried using 'ToList()' and I do get the wrong ID. Oddly the SQL produced seems correct and provides the correct result in management studio. Just trying to write a unit test to prove it's broken - although that insisted in some additional code migrations before running and passed once I'd made them.

Comment: Anything special with the `ID`? Is it just an `int` with default `get`/`set`?

Comment: @BenAaronson: Just a plain old int - I've added an Edit to illustrate. I'm mightly confused now - seems that the problem's all around selecting from the database but I don't understand why a website and a test (pointing to the same DB) return aren't consistent.

Comment: @BenAaronson: Managed to isolate the fact that if I run the same request ' this.context.ZoneMappings.Include("Zone").Where(z => z.Zone.ID == 257 && z.PostcodeKey == "2214")' from a different section of code in the same AppDomain it works.

Comment: I'm rather stumped for the moment, I'm afraid!

Comment: @BenAaronson: No problem - I'm posting a new question with a bit clearer information and more to the point on what we've discovered.

Comment: @Ian: That is indeed mighty weird. Link your new question here for those interested. I'm not sure how much more help I can be but I'd like to hear the end of the story if possible! :)

Comment: @Ian - is there no Zone_ID property on your ZoneMapping class you could compare instead of Zone?

Comment: @JamesS: Nope, that's hidden by EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the problem was actually demonstrated more clearly with a Where clause instead. The actual problem was due to the PrimaryKey being applied on an Entity, rather than a simple field. See [Where returns wrong record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539709/where-returns-wrong-record) for more details