# Where returns wrong record

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

**UPDATE**

I've just had a thought that may well be relevant to this issue. I'm using a code first approach with this project. Originally my ZoneMapping class was defined as you can see below, however the database only had a single PrimaryKey field in the database. I believe because EF hadn't interpreted the data quite correctly.

At this point I made a modification to my <strike>migration</strike> SQL script output to add the additional primary key that I applied to the database. I've just updated the migration instead from:

```
       CreateTable(
            "dbo.NetC_EF_ZoneMapping",
            c => new
                {
                    PostcodeKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Zone_ID = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.PostcodeKey)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.NetC_EF_Zone", t => t.Zone_ID)
            .Index(t => t.Zone_ID);
```

I've just tried adding an additional PrimaryKey manually in the migration after the PostcodeKey one has been defined.

```
 .PrimaryKey(t => t.Zone_ID)
```

Unfortunately I'm still getting my error - I'm assuming this migration isn't used to build the EF 'model' in code, but I'm wondering if it thinks that there can only be a single entry with any given PostcodeKey which may explain the situation?

---

I'm posting a new question based on [Linq Except not functioning as expected - duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537503/linq-except-not-functioning-as-expected-duplicate-items) because I feel that enough has been discovered that the question is invalid, and Except is not the problem at all.

The problem I have is that I have a Linq Where clause that seems to be returning the wrong data. The data in my database looks like:

[image]

The class that represents this data has a compound key:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a mapping between a postcode and a zone
/// </summary>
[Table("NetC_EF_ZoneMapping")]
public class ZoneMapping
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the postcode identifier
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public String PostcodeKey { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Zone identifier
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public Zone Zone { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm executing the following code, which results in different IDs:

```
var result = this.context.ZoneMappings.Include("Zone").Where(z => z.Zone.ID == 257 && z.PostcodeKey == "2214");
var result2 = new FreightContext().ZoneMappings.Include("Zone").Where(z => z.Zone.ID == 257 && z.PostcodeKey == "2214");
if (result.First().Zone.ID != result2.First().Zone.ID)
     throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

[image]

The SQL (or `ToString()` for these two items is identical). So the only difference is that one is a new context, while the other has been passed in and used for some other stuff. The code that creates the context returning the wrong result is:

```
 // Copy the contents of the posted file to a memory stream
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream))
 using (FreightContext context = new FreightContext())
 {
      // Attempt to run the import
      ZoneMappingCSVImporter importer = new ZoneMappingCSVImporter(sr, context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
      var items = importer.GetItems().ToList();
      importer.SaveItems(items);
      this.successBox.Value = "Import completed and added " + items.Count() + " zones mappings.";
  }
```

This then registers a `ClassMap` in the library that I'm using where:

```
 public ZoneMappingCSVImporter(TextReader textReader, FreightContext context, CultureInfo culture)
 : base(textReader, context, culture)
 {
     this.reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap(new ZoneMappingMap(this.context));
 }
```

I do a lookup using the context:

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ZoneMap"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        public ZoneMappingMap(FreightContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

            Map(m => m.PostcodeKey);
            Map(m => m.Zone).ConvertUsing(row =>
            {
                // Grab the name of the zone then go find this in the database
                String name = row.GetField<String>("Zone");
                return context.Zones.Where(z => String.Compare(z.Name, name, true) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
            });
        }
```

I can't see anything strange going on here, I've verified the SQL generated by Entity Framework, verified the database is the same one - I can't understand why the wrong record would be returned. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: When you say "verified".. do you mean you've looked over both of them? Or you have actually run the queries against the database manually via Management Studio/similar tool? If so.. what do the queries return? Both return the expected Zone with ID 257?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I have compared them both against each other in WinMerge to check them being identical and ran one via Management studio.

Comment: ..and they return the expected row with Zone ID 257? (stupid questions I know.. but I have to ask..)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Yep - same as result2.First(). I also don't mind stupid questions :)

Comment: Have you tried with other where clauses to see if there is any pattern? eg does it always add one, always return the next item in the default ordering, always return that same incorrect record, etc.

Comment: @Chris: I haven't - It's a bit of effort to get to this point, and I couldn't replicate in my unit test (hence me trying another context in my code). I'll see if I can find another example with two identical PostcodeKeys and try it.

Comment: I'm not an EF guru (NHibernate really..) but that mapping of `Zone` in the classmap looks weird to me. The column is `Zone_ID`.. yet that makes no mention anywhere in your code (only `Zone` does..). Is there a part to this that is missing the `Zone_ID` == foreign key column map?

Comment: Given my above comment.. should perhaps `.GetField<string>("Zone")` be `GetField<string>("Zone_ID")`? .. (again, could be a stupid comment.. since I'm not much good with EF classmaps!)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Sorry - Zone_ID is a foreign key field yes. No - the GetField stuff is really unrelated (and is to do with CSV Column mapping). It's there to illustrate how the context that is broken has been used.

Comment: @Chris: Well I've tried to simulate by creating a similar entry in the database but the 'Where' seems to work fine at that point :/

Comment: If you are comparing the first result of those two queries you should really order the sets by that id.

Comment: Also what else have you done on the existing context before running this statement. if you were to have some pending edits they would show up in the query as they exist in the local object graph

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: Hi Luke - in this case both sets are only returning one ID anyway. The context which is having problems has no pending edits by this point, it has purely been used to lookup zones (the last codeblock in my question).

Comment: @Chris: Well I've managed to repeat this with a different set of data and extract it into a unit test, although I'm none the wiser at the moment :/ Also seems if I move the 'Where()' conditions around a little sometimes I don't get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for this problem is most likely the following:

- Your way to define composite primary key in your entity is incorrect. With your current model EF only considers `ZoneMapping.PostcodeKey` as the primary key. More on this and how to fix it below.
- You get a wrong `result` in the case when the corresponding context already contains the entity with `PostcodeKey == "2214"` and `Zone_ID == 256` *before* you run your query. (I guess you never had a wrong `result2`.) When EF loads entities from the database it always looks after the query if an entity with the same key already exists in the context. If yes, the queried entity is thrown away and instead the attached entity is added to the result collection. In your case you are querying for `PostcodeKey == "2214"` and `Zone_ID == 257`. After the query EF picks the values of the primary key from the result row. But because EF "thinks" the primary key is only `PostcodeKey == "2214"` it searches for an attached entity with that key value and finds the entity with `PostcodeKey == "2214"`, but `Zone_ID == 256` and returns that as the result to you. You never get this problem with `result2` because the corresponding context is new and empty, so EF will return the result that just has been loaded, not any older attached entity.

If you want to define a composite key you must have scalar properties for both key parts. You cannot use a navigation property like `ZoneMapping.Zone` as a key part. It means that you must have a property for your column `Zone_ID` in the model class (in addition to the navigation property `Zone`):

```
public class ZoneMapping
{
    public String PostcodeKey { get; set; }

    public int Zone_ID { get; set; }
    public Zone Zone { get; set; }
}
```

Then in order to define a composite key with data annotations you must use the `Column(Order = n)` attribute as already shown in @Jonas Jämtberg's answer. You should also apply the `ForeignKey` attribute to `Zone_ID` because the underscore makes the property name "unconventional" so that EF won't detect it as FK by convention:

```
public class ZoneMapping
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public String PostcodeKey { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Zone"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int Zone_ID { get; set; }
    public Zone Zone { get; set; }
}
```

The migration class that is generated by EF with this mapping should have a primary key definition that looks like this:

```
.PrimaryKey(t => new { t.PostcodeKey, t.Zone_ID })
```

...not like `.PrimaryKey(t => t.PostcodeKey).PrimaryKey(t => t.Zone_ID)` that you tried unsuccessfully to fix the problem.

Comment: That's a great explanation and I'm eager to test - The OrderAttribute doesn't appear to be defined when I try to add it however.

Comment: Realised I needed Column(Order = 1) for EF5 and you are absolutely right with your answer.

Comment: @Ian: Sorry, my mistake, such an `OrderAttribute` actually never existed. `Column(Order = n)` was always the right attribute. I've corrected that.